# Get values from a has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

My setup:

```
class ServiceUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :service

   enum status: [ :unavailable, :available ]
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :service_users
  has_many :users, :through => :service_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :service_users
  has_many :services, :through => :service_users
end
```

From the ServiceUser model i can call the status field, in my case available and unavailable.
In my app i'm listing all the users for a specific service with:

```
@service.users
```

But now i want to show the status for each user from the ServiceUser model. What is the best way to do is?

Also i want to make a form for the ServiceUser model to make a new relation between the service and the current user:

```
ServiceUser.new(service_id: @service.id, user_id: current_user.id, status: 1)
```

What do i need to specify in the form for?

Comment: Have a look at this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180025/how-do-i-reference-and-change-an-extra-value-in-a-has-many-through-model

Answer (score 0):

Construct a hash with user_id as the key and value as the status

```
user_status = Hash[*@service.service_users.map{|su|[su.user_id, su.status] }.flatten]
```

Now you can get the status for each user by

```
@service.users.each do |user|
 p user_status[user.id]
end
```

Comment: Thankyou that worked out!

And now i want to create a form for the ServiceUser model, i added in the services_controller:
    @relation = ServiceUser.new
And in the form
    form_for(@relation) do |f|

But it's giving a routing error